# Help determining which statistics to use

Tags: descriptive-statistics, percentage

Forgive me as I am a novice.  I have done a training for a group and wanted to calculate some stats on the percentage of improvement of knowledge and understanding based on participant survey answers.  For example, for Question A, 55% percent of participants report they didn't understand the concept before training, but 95% understood it after.  What stats would I use?   Thank you!

Comment: the search term "difference of proportions test" might yield interesting results

Comment: So has $55\%$ become $5\%$ and $45\%$ become $95\%$? (Best not to switch results mid-course.) How many people were surveyed, are they the same people, and did they all reply each time?

Comment: 35.7 became 53.3, same people but they did not all reply the second time.